# Using std::copy to copy into an std::deque

Tags: c++

I have a C-style array `unsigned char Temp[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE]` and I want to copy it into an `std::deque` at the end ( more like append it)

```
std::deque<unsigned char>* buffer = new std::deque<unsigned char>();
std::copy(Temp[0], Temp[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE], buffer->cend());
```

And I'm getting a lot of errors like these:

> Error 4   error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when
>   followed by '::'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  371 1   a Error 5   error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of '`global
>   namespace''   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  371 1   a Error 9   error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility    372 1   a
>   Error 12  error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>::value_type' is not
>   a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>' c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility  372 1   a

Comment: Why are you using `new` to instantiate your queue?

Comment: So that I can pass it somewhere else outside the scope of that function

Comment: Better use a `std::unique_ptr<std::deque<unsigned char>>` to achieve this.

Comment: You can pass it somewhere else outside the scope of that function by *returning* it from that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any sense to allocate buffer in the heap. Nevertheless the valid code will look like

```
std::deque<unsigned char>* buffer = new std::deque<unsigned char>();
std::copy( Temp, Temp + SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE, std::back_inserter( *buffer ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE = 6;
    unsigned char Temp[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE] = "Hello";

    std::deque<unsigned char> *buffer = new std::deque<unsigned char>();

    std::copy( Temp, Temp + SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE, std::back_inserter( *buffer ) );

    for ( unsigned char c : *buffer ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello
```

Comment: Better teach the person also to use the relevant constructor and avoid the needless complication, verbosity and inefficiency of `copy` + `back_inserter`. I wonder, when so often the simplest way is also most efficient etc., why do they come up with all these Rube Goldberg schemes. Argh.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf  We do not know in which task these constructions are used. It can be that the deque was already created and is appended somewhere else.

Comment: I meant "also". And also the `insert` member function. Depending on the context a constructor or `insert` will be the rational choice.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf I agree that member function insert should be mentioned. But in any case he must know how to use correctly standard algorithm std::copy.:)

Answer (score 4):

Error tells you what you're doing wrong. `std::copy` takes iterators and you are giving it chars. `Temp[0]` and `Temp[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE]` are just `unsigned char`.

But you don't need `std::copy`, `deque` itself takes a two-iterator constructor:

```
std::deque<unsigned char>* buffer = new std::deque<unsigned char>(Temp, 
                                                Temp + SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

or just:

```
std::deque<unsigned char> buffer(Temp, Temp + SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `std::copy` to do this with `std::deque`. `std::deque` has member function [`std::deque::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/insert/) and you could append a range to it in the following manner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::deque<unsigned char> dq;
  unsigned char buf[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

  dq.insert(dq.end(), buf, buf + 4);

  for (auto i : dq) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Better off, if c++11 is an option, don't use raw pointers and instead use smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<std::deque<unsigned char>> dq(new std::deque<unsigned char>);
  unsigned char buf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

  dq->insert(dq->end(), buf, buf + 4);

  for(auto i : *dq) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  const size_t SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE = 6;
  unsigned char Temp[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE] = "Hello";

  std::deque<unsigned char> buffer(Temp, Temp+SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE);

  for ( auto c : buffer ) 
    std::cout << c;
}
```

I construct it with a range, good thing, it actually emplace values in the deck. If you had big ojects instead of chars, it would be faster than your approach.
protip:
Don't use raw pointers where they're not needed. It's bad practice in C++.

Comment: why are you using ugly eye-damanging uppercase. consider the naming convention for macros and what it's for. what was that again?

Comment: coherence with the naming convention of the OP.